# Dynamic jolt to handle when single element or multiple elements in a array

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

Dynamic jolt to handle when single element or multiple elements in a array

My jolt spec is working perfectly fine if we receive one element, but if they send a JSON involving multiple elements, its failing

Input 1

```json
[
  {
    "c_No": "1275999",
    "c_Season_No": "355335",
    "division_Code": "L",
    "department_Code": "L0A1",
    "product_Thumbnail": "000001/000001/000001/",
    "color_Thumbnail": "000001/000001/000001/"
  }
]
```

Input 2

```json
[
  {
    "c_No": "1275999",
    "c_Season_No": "355335",
    "division_Code": "L",
    "department_Code": "L0A1",
    "product_Thumbnail": "000001/000001/000001/",
    "color_Thumbnail": "000001/000001/000001/"
  },
  {
    "c_No": "1275888",
    "c_Season_No": "355335",
    "division_Code": "L",
    "department_Code": "L0A1",
    "product_Thumbnail": "000001/000001/000001/",
    "color_Thumbnail": "000001/000001/000001/"
  }
]
```

Ouput Expected 1

```json
[
  {
    "c_No": "1275999",
    "c_Season_No": "355335",
    "Department": "LL0A1",
    "ColorwaySeasonImage": "https://www000001/000001/000001",
    "ColorWayImage": "https://www000001/000001/000001",
    "AllPLMItem": "All"
  }
]
```

Output Expected 2

```json
[
  {
    "c_No": "1275999",
    "c_Season_No": "355335",
    "Department": "LL0A1",
    "ColorwaySeasonImage": "https://www000001/000001/000001",
    "ColorWayImage": "https://www000001/000001/000001",
    "AllPLMItem": "All"
  },
  {
    "c_No": "1275888",
    "c_Season_No": "355335",
    "Department": "LL0A1",
    "ColorwaySeasonImage": "https://www000001/000001/000001",
    "ColorWayImage": "https://www000001/000001/000001",
    "AllPLMItem": "All"
  }
]
```

Jolt I hv tried

**logic** :

- If `product_Thumbnail` is **blank**, then `ColorwaySeasonImage` value
  should be **blank**

similarly

- If `color_Thumbnail` is **blank**, then `ColorWayImage` value should be **blank**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Department": "=concat(@(1,division_Code),@(1,department_Code))",
        "ColorwaySeasonImage": "=concat('https://www',@(1,product_Thumbnail))",
        "ColorWayImage": "=concat('https://www',@(1,color_Thumbnail))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "c_No": "c_No",
        "c_Season_No": "c_Season_No",
        "Department": "Department",
        "ColorwaySeasonImage": {
          "https://www": {
            "@0": "&2"
          },
          "https://www*": {
            "@1": "&2"
          }
        },
        "ColorWayImage": {
          "https://www": {
            "@0": "&2"
          },
          "https:www*": {
            "@1": "&2"
          }
        },
        "department": "PLMDepartment\\$DisplayName"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "AllPLMItem": "All",
      "ColorWayImage": "",
      "ColorwaySeasonImage": ""
    }
  }
]
```

Jolt i m using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need *conditionals* to determine the cases *to be* vs. *not to be* ***blank***, and so do need a ***shift*** transformation as well in order to handle them in it.

So start with a ***shift*** transformation, and then concatenate the components through use of ***join*** function within a ***modify*** transformation in order to render reformed arrays such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[&1].&",
        "*_Code": "[&1].Department",
        "product_Thumbnail": {
          "": {
            "$": "[&3].ColorwaySeasonImage" // rename the attribute
          },
          "*": {
            "#https://www|$": "[&3].ColorwaySeasonImage" // rename the attribute
          }
        },
        "color_Thumbnail": {
          "": {
            "# ": "[&3].ColorWayImage"  // rename the attribute
          },
          "*": {
            "#https://www|$": "[&3].ColorWayImage"  // rename the attribute
          }
        },
        "#All": "[&1].AllPLMItem" // fixed value
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "=join('',@(1,&))"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]